# jQuery serialize and json?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

It's been a long time since i used jquery and ajax requests. So, i figured out i may pick it up and start coding a few things again. However, i can't remember this at all. Been trying to read, and i understands the bits and peace but i cant get it together.

What i got, is a simple text input where i can type text. What i want, is to recieve this text back as an md5 hash (done with php and encoding it using json etc) but how would my javascript look like?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yourEncryptionPage.php',
    data { text: $("#textInput").val() },
    success: function(encryptedText) {
        // do something with the encrypted text here...
    }
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

And where exactly do you stuck?

Use Ajax to send your text to your php-script. Do your stuff there and echo it with json_encode function. 
In the success function of your ajax you can handle it.